# how to find all <p> tags under heading

Tags: html, dom

I have to extract data from this link: http://bit.ly/l1rF5x

What I want to do is that I want to extract all p tags which comes under the `<a>` tag having attribute `rel="bookmark"`. My only requirement is that only `<p>` tags which comes under this heading should be parsed, and remaining should be left as it is. Like for example  in this page which I have given you, all `<p>` tags which comes under heading "IIFT question paper 2006", should be parsed.

help please.

Comment: Do you want to do this on server or client side? What kind of langugae are you using?

Comment: Please don't use shortened URLs when not necessary; I like to know where I'm going to *before* I click a link.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any information about the language / environment you want to use to extract this information, I've gone ahead and hacked something together with jQuery.

(Updated) You can see it in action here: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yF4nQ/3/).

If you wanted to use PHP, I recommend [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Here is an example using simplehtmldom:

```
$url = 'http://school-listing.mba4india.com/page/7/';

$html = file_get_html($url);

$data = array();

// Find all anchors with the desired rel attribute
foreach ($html->find('a[rel="bookmark"]') as $a) {
    $h4 = $a->parent(); // Get the anchors parent (in this case an h4)

    // We're assuming the next sibling is a p tag here - should test for this here
    $p = $h4->next_sibling(); 

    $content = '';

    // Iterate over all following p tags, until we run out of siblings or find one
    // that isn't a p tag
    while ($p) {
        $content .= (string) $p;
        if ($p->next_sibling() && $p->next_sibling()->tag == 'p') {
            $p = $p->next_sibling();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    $data[] = array('h4' => $h4, 'content' => $content);
}

$br = '<br/>';

foreach ($data as $datum) {
    echo $datum['h4'] . $br . $datum['content'];
    echo $br.$br;
}
```

Refer to [Simplehtmldom Documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) for more!

Comment: hey thanks that was cool. But I want to implement that with php. as u mentioned I am using simplehtmldom but somehow I am unable to write the code for it.

Comment: also one more thing, the code written in jquery only prints first <p> tag but I want to print all the p tags which comes under it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following :

```
$(function(){
    var results= '';
    $('a[rel="bookmark"] p').each(function(i,e){
        results += $(e).html() + "\n";
    });
        alert(results);
});
```

Variable results will be alerted with the required content. 
Example : http://jsfiddle.net/eGmWw/1/